# Parsing JSON data to C# Object

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I have JSON file which contains multiple arrays of objects:

```
{
    "projects":[{
        "issuetypes":[{
            "fields":{
                "priority":{
                "allowedValues":[{
                    "self":"",
                    "iconUrl":"",
                    "name":"",
                    "id":"1"
                }]
            },
            "components":{
            "allowedValues":[{
                "self":"",
                "id":"",
                "name":""
            }
```

And I tried to parse it to C# class.

Google have examples only with simplified version of deserializing JSON do C# Object.

What I created now ?

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "projects")]
    public List<ProjectObject> Projects { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectObject
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "issueTypes")]
    public List<IssueObject> Issues { get; set; }
}

public class IssueObject
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "fields")]
    public FieldObject Field { get; set; }
}

public class FieldObject
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "components")]
    public ComponentObject Component { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "priority")]
    public PriorityObject Priority { get; set; }
}

public class PriorityObject
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
    public PriorityAllowedValues PriorityValues { get; set; }
}

public class PriorityAllowedValues
{
    public List<PriorityValues> AllowedValues { get; set; }
}

public class PriorityValues
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "self")]
    public string Self { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "iconUrl")]
    public string IconUrl { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ComponentObject
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
    public ComponentAllowedValues ComponentAllowedValues { get; set; }
}

public class ComponentAllowedValues
{
    public List<SelectObject> AllowedValues { get; set; }
}

public class SelectObject
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "self")]
    public string Self { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And when I am trying to execute this line:

```
RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(data);
```

Data from JSON file should go properly to RootObject...

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: My problem is that it's not going properly... Have you got any idea how it should be properly ?

Comment: *not going properly* is not a useful response to anyone. What is the *exact* problem? Do you have errors? What is your expected outcome and how does it differ from what you are getting?

Comment: From a quick glance it does not look like your classes match your Json 100%.  You might want to take another look...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some tools which can help you generate classes from JSON, e.g. https://jsonutils.com/ 
This structure should work for provided json:

```
public class AllowedValue
{

    [JsonProperty("self")]
    public string Self { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("iconUrl")]
    public string IconUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class Priority
{

    [JsonProperty("allowedValues")]
    public IList<AllowedValue> AllowedValues { get; set; }
}

public class AllowedValue
{

    [JsonProperty("self")]
    public string Self { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Components
{

    [JsonProperty("allowedValues")]
    public IList<AllowedValue> AllowedValues { get; set; }
}

public class Fields
{

    [JsonProperty("priority")]
    public Priority Priority { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("components")]
    public Components Components { get; set; }
}

public class Issuetype
{

    [JsonProperty("fields")]
    public Fields Fields { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{

    [JsonProperty("issuetypes")]
    public IList<Issuetype> Issuetypes { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{

    [JsonProperty("projects")]
    public IList<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @maccettura, you're right, I've updated the code and added the tool which generates classes in PascalCase

Comment: I am pretty sure that `[JsonProperty]` shouldn't be needed if the casing is different, it should only be needed if the _text_ is different.  The default behavior internally is to use `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` I believe.  Dont quote me on that but it might be worth looking into